# Copying from a table row to spreadsheet with formula

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have this sample data from my HTML table row.

```
Tester  sample@gmail.com                        2018-07-19  1000    1200        new
```

And I am copying this data to google spreadsheet with a formula of the total of two columns. But when copying the data, the cell with formula will be overridden and removed. Like the sample image below:

[image]

Is there a way or function that will automatically create the formula for the two cells? 
I tried getting the column letter and row number and combine them so that it will give me the formula. Like `=SUM(column(Letter here)row(): column(Letter here)row()` But this doesn't give me the column letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all,
   you know that it’s overkill to use `SUM` to add two cells, right? 
   It’s good enough to say `=F53+G53`. 
   But, of course, `SUM` comes in handy when you want to add many numbers;
   e.g., `=SUM(A53:G53)`.
2. The simple way to add Column `F` and Column `G` in the current row
   without hard-coding the row number in the formula is

   ```
   =INDEX(F:F,ROW()) + INDEX(G:G,ROW())
   ```

   If you want the general solution, you can do

   ```
   =SUM(INDEX(F:F,ROW()):INDEX(G:G,ROW()))
   ```